# Where can I see which of my comments have been flagged by others?

Tags: support, comments, flags

I am just curious to know if as a normal user I can check which of my comments have been flagged for moderator attention by others? (I don't want to know who have flagged.)

The aim behind this is if there was something wrong with my comment somewhere so I should avoid that in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Only moderators can see what comments have been flagged.

If there is anything wrong about your comments that the moderators feel requires a change in behaviour from you, they can reply to one of your posts or comments, or leave you a private moderator message to provide feedback.